# Not Able to Install any Windows Version

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

I have a problem with Windows installation on my laptop. Here is what I have done so far;

I tried using 2 different USB (16 GB Toshiba and some other 8GB USB) to install Windows.

I tried burning to a DVD and install.

I tried both NTFS and Fat32 as installation options.

I tried Rufus, WinToFlash, Windows Media Creation Tool (Downloaded Windows 10 and made boot USB)

I tried installing Windows 7. When the installation completes, I can open Windows 7, but when I install either CPU driver or a GPU driver blue screen error comes. If I open with Safe Mode and delete the drivers and then do Recovery, it works but again when I install one of the drivers it's game over. All the drivers I try to install are the correct and most up-to-date drivers.

I tried installing Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. After successful installation of them I receive immediately blue screen error (after the first reboot when the install complete). None of the Troubleshoot options works, none of the CMD codes I have tried works.

In total I must have at least tried installing Windows 20 times (a combination of all the things above)

I have used HD-Tune Pro to find if there is any problem with the disk. I ran the Error Scan (Long one) and all green, no problem with the disk, no bad sectors. Health option also shows all OK. The disk I am using is Corsair Force GS 120 GB SSD.

I was using Ubuntu before I uninstalled it and tried to use Windows. Right now, after all those fails, I went back to Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works right now, however, I need to use Windows and I don't want to use it inside a virtual machine from Ubuntu.

My guess is there is something wrong with either my BIOS or there is an actual hardware problem with my GPU (I recently renewed the thermal paste on GPU and CPU so there is a slight chance that I might have damaged something though I have been doing this for years and I highly doubt that's the case).

My laptop is MSI GE620DX-802xtr, the only change I made few years ago was to change the HDD to this SSD (I have used Windows on this exact system before like a year ago and then had to install Ubuntu for work and now trying to go back to Windows). The system is right now like this;

- CPU: Intel Core i5 2450m
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT 635M and Intel HD Graphics 3000
- RAM: 6GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- SSD: Corsair Force GS 120GB

Here is how my BIOS looks like;

```
https://postimg.org/image/klydti551/
https://postimg.org/image/sep1lit4l/
https://postimg.org/image/50h29lqmt/
https://postimg.org/image/uw0ssskqt/
```

Even though HD-Tune says it's fine, is there still any chance that the SSD is indeed problematic? (though you can see that right now Ubuntu is installed and computer works fine so, no I guess).

What am I missing here?

Comment: So, the installation appears to completed successfully, but the first time you attempt to run the computer after the installation you receive a blue screen error? What message does this error give?

Comment: Your BIOS snapshots are inaccessible.

Comment: Yes after the installation it gives blue screen, all of the errors were different like sometimes it was syntp.sys sometimes 0x0000001.. I checked them all to see any solutions but nothing works since every single time I install windows, I get a blue screen error..

Comment: @AFH                   changed the links should be working now

Comment: Also just tried now to Install Windows 10 under VM in ubuntu and even that gives blue screen error. That's some crazy thing. How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me after using Ubuntu

Run ur install again and try this.

2) Navigate Repair Your Computer --> Command Prompt.

3) In the Command Prompt window,  type diskpart and press enter.

4) Type list disk and press Enter to list all the disk drives.

5) Type select disk + disk number, here you can find the number of the target disk by referring to the listed disk information.

6) Type clean to wipe all files and folders on the selected disk.

7) Type create partition primary and press Enter.

8) After diskpart successfully created the specified partition, type format fs=ntfs (or format fs=exfat) and press Enter. You're telling diskpart to format the drive with a file system, let it be NTFS, exFAT, etc.

9) At last, assign a drive letter to the newly created partition by typing assign.

Might take a few tries

Then try re installing  if windows 7 doesn’t work try 10

Comment: I did them all just like you said 1 by 1 and tried to install again but still having a bluescreen.. Code 0xc0000221 bxvbda.sys error again..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a faulty RAM. I had 2 RAMs running ( 2GB + 4GB ) and once I removed the 4GB from the system, everything started to work.. Therefore, solution was indeed hardware based.

Comment: Run Memtest86 from Ubuntus live menu on the 4GB only, shame to waste the 4GB if it's just not compatible with the 2GB

Comment: They are the same brand same model same 1300 mhz etc. but thanks for the advice I will make an Ubuntu live dvd and try the method you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try burning using another program called Ultra ISO and make sure **write method** is set to **USB-HDD**

Comment: I tried it just now and done exactly the way you said. However, nothing changed. Installation completes and immediately after the first reboot, another blue screen comes..

I dont think the problem is related to the installation process but I can't figure out the reason for this happening.